# Web security features from host provider

Tags: web-hosting, web-development, security

I am working with a contractor to get a website built with text, video, facebook and twitter integration. No commercial transaction, just plain information sharing.

I want to secure my website and hence came to this link which illustrates basic security features that website needs to have:

https://www.eukhost.com/blog/webhosting/features-to-make-your-website-secure/

Which of the features in link above does the contractor needs to build for me and which of them are expected to be provided by a good host. I am considering using GoDaddy.

Edit: Thanks for the answer. Any other recommended security feature that you can think of and I should ask the contractor or host is also appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

To cover all the items in that list:

- SSL - nowadays there is no need to pay for SSL certificates thanks to LetsEncrypt, so don't be conned into it.  SSL doesn't protect your site as such, it encrypts traffic to and from, protecting the data. Contractor
- FTP - even if you aren't going to use it, you likely can't disable it, so ensure that it has a *really* secure password. Contractor/you
- SFTP - as above, it is a secure form of FTP just has https is a secure form of http. Contractor/you
- SSH - this is where someone can do real damage.  I don't think godaddy gives SSH access, if they do, the standard port should be changed so any access attempts have an initial hurdle to overcome. Host
- Spam - do not publish *any* email addresses, they *will* be hoovered up.  Use forms with some sort of captcha.  Contractor
- hot links - there will be an option in cpanel to disable hotlinking.  You
- DDOS - that is for the provider, however without going into all the other problems with godaddy, unless you are on a VPS you are going to be sharing a machine with *thousands* of other sites.  If one of them attracts an attack, it is going to affect you.  Host